# Updating Seaborn distplot code to version 0.11

Tags: python, seaborn

Using distplot to plot a histogram

```
sns.distplot(a, color="red", label="100% Equities")
```

and running this under Seaborn version 0.11 or greater produces the following warning:

> FutureWarning: `distplot` is a deprecated function and will be removed
> in a future version. Please adapt your code to use either `displot` (a
> figure-level function with similar flexibility) or `histplot` (an
> axes-level function for histograms).   warnings.warn(msg,
> FutureWarning)

Using **displot** as a direct replacement (simply changing the function name from **distplot** to **displot**) does not produce the same histogram.

What is the replacement code?

Comment: label doesn't seem to be a parameter of displot: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html

Comment: The code above is for distplot (not displot). distplot is the deprecated code and it does have a label.

Also histplot (see the answer below) does inherit label from bar. If you chase down through the kwargs in the link you have given (select histplot, then at the end select bar -- you will find the label keyword is available.) Matplotlib does a lot of inheriting :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use

- `histplot` instead of `distplot`
- and add the keyword args  `kde=True, stat="density", linewidth=0`

So:

```
sns.histplot(a, color="red", label="100% Equities", kde=True, stat="density", linewidth=0)
```

replaces

```
sns.distplot(a, color="red", label="100% Equities")
```

Answer (score 4):

**Example of Code for Hisplot to show the frequency of first state and zero state of the machine at each point:**

```
feature2_ok = df.loc[df["target"] == 1]

feature2_ng = df.loc[df["target"] == 0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 6))
sns.histplot(feature2_ok["feature_2"], color="orange", label="100% Equities", kde=True, linewidth=0)

sns.histplot(feature2_ng["feature_2"], label="100% Equities", kde=True, linewidth=0)

ax.set(xlim=(-100, 700), 
 xticks=[-100, -50, 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700])

plt.legend(["Frist State", "Zero State"])

plt.title('Machine Performance Feature 2')

plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
sns.histplot(your_data, kde=True)
```